# How to become a public baker?

Tags: node, public-node, mytezosbaker

I've been solo baking for over a year now for me and a few friends. I recently have set up tezos-rewards-distributor and it's working fine.

Now I would like to become a public baker but can't figure out how to get listed.
I've read that one can register with mytezosbaker.com but this site now just redirects to tezos.com

Thanks a lot
RonnyRenner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get listed on [Baking Bad](https://baking-bad.org/) and [TzKT](https://tzkt.io/bakers/) as a public baker, just contact our support on [twitter](https://twitter.com/tezosbakingbad), [telegram](https://t.me/baking_bad_chat), [discord](https://discord.gg/aG8XKuwsQd) or email us hello@baking-bad.org and we'll walk you through

Answer (score 1):

Being a "private baker" simply means you are not advertising your services. There is no setting that enables you private or public baker. Technically, every baker on Tezos is public.

To be a "public baker" you simply advertise yourself as such. You must contact each of the major explorers (tzkt, tzstats, etc) and request your profile be updated. Get a website, branding, etc. Establish your fee, minimum delegation amount, payout policy as well. There's "work" to be done here.